# Assigning Field-Symbol from table with several conditions and deeper structure

Tags: abap

I want to get the line where `segnam = 'E1IDB02'` and `sdata` starting with `BB` (-> `sdata` has a deeper structure. Therefore `sdata` has the type of the `segnam`. Thus means for the example further down, the first to rows have the type E1IDB02 and `sdata` in the third row has the type E1IDKU3. This will be clearer if you see the example coding further down) and then update a field in the structure in `sdata`.

For example I have following `t_edidd`-table:

| segnam | sdata |
| --- | --- |
| E1IDB02 | BA 123456 ... |
| E1IDB02 | BB 987654 ... |
| E1IDKU3 | ... |

One working solution:

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <ls_e1idb02> TYPE e1idb02.


LOOP AT t_edidd ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lv_edidd>) WHERE segnam = 'E1IDB02' AND sdata(2) = 'BB'.

  ASSIGN <lv_edidd>-sdata TO <ls_e1idb02> CASTING.
  <ls_e1idb02>-fiibkont = `01`.

ENDLOOP.
```

Or to be a little bit more clear:

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <ls_e1idb02> TYPE e1idb02.

LOOP AT t_edidd ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lv_edidd>) WHERE segnam = 'E1IDB02'.

  ASSIGN <lv_edidd>-sdata TO <ls_e1idb02> CASTING.
  IF <ls_e1idb02>-fiiquali = 'BB'. "<----
    <ls_e1idb02>-fiibkont = `01`.
  ENDIF.

ENDLOOP.
```

I wonder if there is a better solution for this?

What I have in mind is something like this (**not working!**):

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <ls_e1idb02> TYPE e1idb02.
ASSIGN t_edidd[ segnam = 'E1IDB02' sdata-fiiquali = 'BB' ]-sdata TO <ls_e1idb02> CASTING.
<ls_e1idb02>-fiibkont = `01`.
```

`ASSIGN t_edidd[ segnam = 'E1IDB02' ]-sdata TO <result> CASTING.` would work if I only have one entry with `segnam = 'E1IDB02'` but I need a second condition for sdata starting with BB or sdata field `fiiquali` of the structure `E1IDB02`.

What is working is following:

```
ASSIGN t_edidd[ segnam = 'E1IDB02' sdata(2) = 'BB' ]-sdata TO <ls_e1idb02> CASTING.
<ls_e1idb02>-fiibkont = `01`.
```

But due I want to cast the type of `sdata` into the structure `e1idb02` getting the first 2 digits of `sdata` is not intentional in my opinion.

Hope my problem was understandable. If there is any information missing please let me know.

If someone wants to try this by themself I also wrote a unit test for my problem:

```
METHOD test.
  DATA: ls_e1idb02  TYPE e1idb02,
        ls_edidd    TYPE edidd,
        t_edidd     TYPE TABLE OF edidd,
        t_edidd_exp TYPE TABLE OF edidd.


  ls_edidd-segnam = 'E1IDB02'.
  ls_e1idb02-fiiquali = 'BA'.
  ls_edidd-sdata = ls_e1idb02.
  APPEND ls_edidd TO t_edidd.
  APPEND ls_edidd TO t_edidd_exp.

  ls_edidd-segnam = 'E1IDB02'.
  ls_e1idb02-fiiquali = 'BB'.
  ls_edidd-sdata = ls_e1idb02.
  APPEND ls_edidd TO t_edidd.

  ls_e1idb02-fiibkont = `01`.
  ls_edidd-sdata = ls_e1idb02.
  APPEND ls_edidd TO t_edidd_exp.

  zclass->test(
    CHANGING
      t_edidd = t_edidd
  ).

  cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_equals(
    act = t_edidd
    exp = t_edidd_exp
  ).
ENDMETHOD.
```

Comment: I think that people use your "little bit more clear" solution, which is short and clear. For information, ABAP provide more concise statements at each version (e.g. [ABAP 2108](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/03/28/new-kinds-of-abap-expressions-part-ii/)) but I think there's nothing yet to simplify your specific case.

Comment: it worth mentioning about these statements you mentioned: Everything in this section only works since CE 2108 or kernel 7.86. **It is not yet contained in any on-premise release**

Comment: `I wonder if there is a better solution for this?` what exactly you wanna "improve" in your solution? you wanna filter by SDATA structure fields?

Comment: @Suncatcher I do not want to use many loops in my programs due to performance. Therefore I would like to assign directly to a field-symbol (ig this is more efficient regarding performance). And the working solution with `sdata(2) = 'BB'` looks not so keen to me because what happens when the structure of E1IDB02 is changing? Maybe `fiiquali` is not the first element in this structure anymore then. Therefore my idea was to cast the element sdata (type `lchr(1000)`) to E1IDB02 inside of `t_edidd` selection. But ig this is not possible, therefore the loop option suits best for this issue.

Comment: You will not bring here neither performance nor readability by putting smth like `t_edidd[ sdata-fiiquali = 'BB' ]`. The performance toll taken by loops in this snippet is negligible compared to what compiler must do dynamically casting and casting the sdata field. The table expression `itab[ a = b ]` is nothing more than a READ TABLE statement, which does looping under the hood, you are reinventing the wheel here. You'd better putting more safeguarding constructions like TRY CATCH and sy-subrc checking if your CASTing goes wrong